# Finding the error of a Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

When calculating the error of a Taylor series, the formula is as follows: $$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)(x-c)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}$$ 
$z$ is the maximum value of the expression on the interval between $x$ and $c$.

Is $z$ the maximum value on the error expression or the original expression? I have been assuming the error expression because we want to know the maximum error. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, $z$ (that you'd better denote $\xi$ to avoid any ambiguity) is just the   value r in the Taylor-Lagrange  form of the remainder: the theorem  asserts there exists some $\xi$ between $a$ and $x$ such that the error is
$$ R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)(x-c)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}, $$
so that, if we have a bound $M$ for $|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)|$ on some interval centred at $c$, we can deduce that
$$ |R_n(x)|\le \frac{M|x-c|^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}. $$

Comment: So how do you find $M$?

Comment: Is it the maximum value of the original function between $x$ and $c$?

Comment: No. It is the value of the derivative of order $n+1$ at some poitn $\xi$.  You cannot say more *a priot*, exactly as in the *Mean value theorem*. Finding $M$ depends on the function, and it  is not always possible to find an effective bound.

Comment: If I know what I'm approximating - is there a way to find this error or it will always have a z?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the function. As far as I know, there is no general rule.